# Javascript coding format between hash and class

Tags: javascriptmvc, javascript

Hi all i had started by javascript coding in functional style implementation but later when my code got more complex and i started to revamp coding using modular approach. This is my first approach with code 1.

Code 1 :

```
var ListModel={
    _items:[],
    _selectedIndex:-1,
    getItems : function () {
        return [].concat(this._items);
    },
    addItem : function (item) {
        this._items.push(item);
    }
}
```

And later in different tutorial i got this kind of approach.

Code 2:

```
function ListModel(items) {
    this._items = items;
    this._selectedIndex = -1;
}

ListModel.prototype = {
    getItems : function () {
        return [].concat(this._items);
    },

    addItem : function (item) {
        this._items.push(item);
    },

    removeItemAt : function (index) {
        var item;
        item = this._items[index];
        this._items.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Which one is better and what these code signify as compared to functional style approach. ?

Please help me ...

Comment: okay thanks Kazekage Gaara got the difference between two. Closure is some kind of code seperation where each code function maintains its own scope and has less chance of variable collisions it may be used for js per html file kind of approach. But for prototype based we can create instances and reuse codes. it may be coded once and used for multiple pages some kind of library. approach

Comment: The link got me cleared thanks.

Comment: Code 1 only supports a singleton (one statically declared instance of the object).  Code 2 allows you to create as many instances as you want with `new ListModel(x)` and for that reason can be used in many more circumstances.

Comment: Code 2 must be the better approach for coding in javascript.